# Regular Expression which matches two duplicate consecutive characters within string but not three or more. Should match if both 'aa' and 'bbb' exist

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

My original question was closed for being a duplicate. I disagree with it being a duplicate as this is a different use case looking at regular expression syntax. I have tried to clarify my question below.

Is it possible to create a regular expression which matches two duplicate consecutive characters within a string (in this example lowercase letters) but does not match a section of the string if the same characters are either side. e.g. match `'aa'` but not `'aaa'` or `'aaaa'`?

*Additionally:*

- Although I am using Python 3.10 I am trying to work out if this is possible using 'standard' regular expression syntax without utilising additional functionality provided by external modules. For example using Python this would mean a solution which uses the `'re'` module from the standard library.
- If there are 3 or more duplicate consecutive characters, the string should still match if there are two duplicate consecutive characters elsewhere in the sting. e.g match `'aa'` even if `'bbb'` exists elsewhere in the string.
- The string should also match if the two duplicate consecutive characters appear at the beginning or end of the string.
- My examples are 16 character strings if a specific length makes a difference.

### Examples:

`ffumlmqwfcsyqpss` should **match** either `'ff'` or `'ss'`.

`zztdcqzqddaazdjp` should **match** either `'zz'`,`'dd'`, `'aa'`.

`urrvucyrzzzooxhx` should **match** `'rr'` or `'oo'` even though `'zzz'` exists in the string.

`zettygjpcoedwyio` should **match** `'tt'`.

`dtfkgggvqadhqbwb` should **not match** `'ggg'`.

`rwgwbwzebsnjmtln` should **not match**.

### What I had originally tried

`([a-z])\1` to capture the duplicate character but this also matches when there are additional duplicate characters such as `'aaa'` or `'aaaa'` etc.

`([a-z])\1(?!\1)` to negate the third duplicate character but this just moves the match to the end of the duplicate character string.

Negative lookarounds to compensate for a match at the beginning but I think I am causing some kind of loop which will never match.

```py
>>>import re

>>>re.search(r'([a-z])\1(?!\1)', 'dtfkgggvqadhqbwb')
<re.Match object; span=(5, 7), match='gg'> # should not match as 'gg' ('[gg]g' or 'g[gg]')
```

### Currently offered solutions don't match described criteria.

- [*Wiktor Stribiżew's* solution](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gquoQsFWoUhdIzpRtypWM8aw2kinVkMr2NszQFNDy02zBiZhpM5VUJSZV6IB0adXnJpYlJyhUVSho6BelVpSUpmeVZCcn5pSXpmZr66poIlbdUpJWnZ6enpZYWJKRmFSeRJI9f//AA) uses the additional `(*SKIP)` functionality of the [external python regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).
- [*Tim Biegeleisen's* solution](https://regexr.com/6amja) does not match duplicate pairs if there are duplicate triples etc in the same string.
- In the linked question, *Cary Swoveland's* solutions [do not work for duplicate pairs](https://regexr.com/6amjj) at the beginning or end of a string or [match even when there is no duplicate in the string](https://regexr.com/6amjp).
- In the linked question, [*the fourth bird's* solution](https://regexr.com/6amjs) does not match duplicate pairs at the beginning or end of strings.

### Summary

So far the only answer which works is Wiktor Stribiżew's but this uses the `(*SKIP)` function of the external 'regex' module. Is a solution not possible using 'standard' regular expression syntax?

Comment: The wording used in the original thread is that _'it is much more convenient'_ to use the `regex` module with its added functionality, not that it is _not possible_ to match the string without it. So it is not possible to match the criteria using _standard_ regular expression syntax? I am trying to learn regex so am very interested in confirmation of this.

Comment: Ok, let's update the thread with another answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Python `re`, the main problem with creating the right regex for this task is the fact that you need to define the capturing group before using a backreference to the group, and negative lookbehinds are usually placed before the captured pattern. Also, regex101.com Python testing option is not always reflecting the current state of affairs in the `re` library, and it confuses users with the message like "*This token can not be used in a lookbehind due to either making it non-fixed width or interfering with the pattern matching*" when it sees a `\1` in `(?<!\1)`, while Python allows this since v3.5 *for groups of fixed length*.

The pattern you can use here is

```py
(.)(?<!\1.)\1(?!\1)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.%29%28%3F%3C!%5C1.%29%5C1%28%3F!%5C1%29&i=ffumlmqwfcsyqpss%0D%0Azztdcqzqddaazdjp%0D%0Aurrvucyrzzzooxhx%0D%0Azettygjpcoedwyio%0D%0Adtfkgggvqadhqbwb%0D%0Arwgwbwzebsnjmtln).

***Details***

- `(.)` - Capturing group 1: any single char (if `re.DOTALL` is used, even line break chars)
- `(?<!\1.)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is the same char as captured in Group 1 and then any single char (we can use `\1` instead of the `.` here, and it will work the same) immediately to the left of the current location
- `\1` - same char as in Group 1
- `(?!\1)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is the same char as in Group 1 immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Python test](https://ideone.com/EJoidL):

```py
import re
tests ={'ffumlmqwfcsyqpss': ['ff','ss'],
    'zztdcqzqddaazdjp': ['zz','dd', 'aa'],
    'urrvucyrzzzooxhx': ['rr','oo'],
    'zettygjpcoedwyio': ['tt'],
    'dtfkgggvqadhqbwb': [],
    'rwgwbwzebsnjmtln': []
}


for test, answer in tests.items():
    matches = [m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'(.)(?<!\1.)\1(?!\1)', test, re.DOTALL)]
    if matches:
        print(f"Matches found in '{test}': {matches}. Is the answer expected? {set(matches)==set(answer)}.")
    else:
        print(f"No match found in '{test}'. Is the answer expected? {set(matches)==set(answer)}.")
```

Output:

```
Matches found in 'ffumlmqwfcsyqpss': ['ff', 'ss']. Is the answer expected? True.
Matches found in 'zztdcqzqddaazdjp': ['zz', 'dd', 'aa']. Is the answer expected? True.
Matches found in 'urrvucyrzzzooxhx': ['rr', 'oo']. Is the answer expected? True.
Matches found in 'zettygjpcoedwyio': ['tt']. Is the answer expected? True.
No match found in 'dtfkgggvqadhqbwb'. Is the answer expected? True.
No match found in 'rwgwbwzebsnjmtln'. Is the answer expected? True.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex pattern:

```
^(?![a-z]*([a-z])\1{2,})[a-z]*([a-z])\2[a-z]*$
```

### Demo

This pattern says to match:

```regex
^                        start of the string
(?![a-z]*([a-z])\1{2,})  same letter does not occur 3 times or more
[a-z]*                   zero or more letters
([a-z])                  capture a letter
\2                       which is followed by the same letter
[a-z]*                   zero or more letters
$                        end of the string
```

Comment: This solution [nearly works](https://regexr.com/6amja) but does not match if both `'aa'` and `'bbb'` exist in the same string. e.g. it does not match the `'rr'` in `'urrvucyrzzzooxhx'` due to the `'zzz'`. I have edited my original question to try and make this requirement clearer. Is it possible to tweak this solution to work with this requirement? I think the use of the negative lookahead `(?![a-z]*([a-z])\1{2,})` in its current form would need to be changed somehow?